# Inject script in my website, but run in other domain

Tags: javascript

I would like to know, if is possible, and if its, how to inject a script in my website, but run it in other website. For example:

```
+--------+
| Site 1 | <- Where I want inject the script
+--------+

+--------+
| Site 2 | <- Where the code of the script is and where will run
+--------+
```

I want use one of my domains as host of my scripts, but not only that, it would be more or less like a frame, the script would be load and run in the Site 1, through Site 2. I'm doing this because the script I want run it's from a service, and I don't want show the url from Site 1, only from Site 2 to this service. I want hide my real site.

I was trying to inject like a normal script:

But this will download the script and run it in Site 1. So, can you guys help me?

Thank you.

Comment: you're going to need something server side on site 1 (php) to get the script from site 2 (maybe via curl)

Comment: A solution I can think of is creating some API on `site 1` that uses the script. Then from `site 2` you can call the API whose address is `site 2` and then `site 2` will do the calls of the script and return the result to `site 1`.

Comment: Can you provide me with a really simple example? I'm trying to draw it in my mind what u said but i'm not getting it

Comment: @JoãoCalvin let me know if my answer is what you're after or not. If not, I can remove it

Comment: What if I open a socket from Site 1 frontend - Site 1 backend - Site 2 ?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what exactly you are asking; do you want to establish a proxy API on Site 1 that forwards queries to Site 2, then Site 2 calls whatever the service is, then returns the result back to Site 1?

Comment: @KenY-N I want run a service (like google analytics for example) without showing my URL (I mean, without letting the service tracking my URL), how to do it I really don't know

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using PHP:

Site 1:

- **/index.php**

  ```
  <?php
  $script = file_get_contents('http://site2.example.com/myscript.js');

  ...
  ?>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script><?= $script ?></script>
    </head>
    ...
  </html>
  ```

Site 2:

- **/myscript.js**

  ```
  console.log("Hello from site 2");
  ```

Comment: This answer does not address "the script would be load and run in the Site 1, through Site 2"

Comment: @Isaac, not exactly that. I would like to run in the Site 1, through Site 2, this way the service won't know my actually URL

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to set the origin of your code and the assign the other accepted domains.

The origin domain will be for user interactions and you can set an accepted source to serve your scripts.

Comment: He wants to hide the URL though

Comment: He use the origin source the the users to interact with and an accepted domain to serve the scripts